# Why won't texture load at all in three.js?

Tags: three.js

So I have been trying to add a texture to the cube, but for some particular reason the texture never loads and all I get is a black 3D model which is the cube. Everything else is working smoothly except for the texturing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3D Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module">
        import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.159.0/build/three.module.js';

        var scene, camera, renderer, cube;

        function init() {
            var container = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(container);

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(65, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            camera.position.z = 300;

            var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100);
            var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            var cubeTexture = loader.load('test.png'); 

            var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: cubeTexture });
            cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
            scene.add(cube);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
            cube.rotation.z += 0.01;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        init();
        animate();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried many different things like different image formats, tried different mesh forms.

Comment: Do you just load that html in the browser and the texture is on you local drive?

Comment: yes that is what I am currently doing, is there something wrong with that?

Comment: The browser cannot access your local drive. You have to set up a http server.

Comment: Can I instead use base64? if so how can I carry that out